# Searching in XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2008

What is best way to search in XML document to retrieve one or more records against search criteria. Suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML if you possibly can. Your question is very vague at the moment, but for example, you could write:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var matches = doc.Descendants("Person")
                 .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == "Jon")
                 .Where(x => x.Elements("Child").Count() >= 2);
```

While you *can* use XPath, I generally prefer not to - it has all the normal problems of embedding one language within another, whereas using LINQ to XML you're using C# throughout, so you have no new syntax to learn - just the relevant methods within the LINQ to XML library.

LINQ to XML also makes namespace handling simple, and you don't need to worry about escaping values etc, as your query is all in code rather than in a string.

Answer (score 2):

.net xml documents have good support for xpath.

It should work for most of your xml searches.

Take a look at [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use `XPath` by *[XmlDocument.SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx)* or *SelectSingleNode* like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("bookstore.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

// Add the namespace.
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "urn:newbooks-schema");

// Select and display the first node in which the author's 
// last name is Kingsolver.
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(
"descendant::bk:book[bk:author/bk:last-name='Kingsolver']", nsmgr);
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerXml);
```